# Blender - show edges angles "direction"

Tags: blender

I'm working on a papercraft project on Pepakura and Valley folds show in light blue and Montain Folds in dark blue.

[image]

I was wondering if there is a way to show the angle of the folding edges directly on Blender ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can see some mesh information in Edit mode.

There is not an angle direction indication (there is only for vertex and face) but it could help a little.

Image below:

[image]

Comment: There is a stackexchange only for blender users here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/